# How to Build matrix in R

Tags: r

I have samples A:Z and I want to make a matrix that have sample column and another value column with all 1's.

result should look like this.

```
samples values
A        1
B        1
C        1
D        1
.        .
.        .
Z        1
```

Comment: @akrun Sorry mate, totally forgot! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cbind` to create a `matrix`

```
 cbind(samples, values=1)
```

but `matrix` can hold only a single `class` so the output columns will be 'character'

I would suggest to use `data.frame` to hold columns of different class.

```
 data.frame(samples, values=1)
```

If we want the 'samples' column to be `character` class, use option `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`.  The default is `TRUE`.